# Error While posting Data to a web application from a windows service."The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm getting this error while trying to post data to a hosted web application from a windows service.

```
 PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter();
            post.Url = "http://192.168.0.1/Invoice/Invoice1.aspx";
            post.PostItems.Add("subscriberid", subscriberid.ToString());
            post.PostItems.Add("StartDate", StartDate);
            post.PostItems.Add("EndDate", EndDate);
            post.PostItems.Add("AdvanceBillDate", AdvanceBillDate);
            post.Type = PostSubmitter.PostTypeEnum.Post;
            try
            {
                string res = post.Post();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

            }
```

This is code snippet of my windows service which posts data to web application.
Does any one know the reason.I'm using asp **.Net C#**

Comment: thats up to the web server. did you write that application?

Comment: ya i did but when i try loading the web application directly frm a browser it works fine.....

Comment: view the logs of that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got wat was missing.Actually i was posting data to the web application and reading it using Request.QueryString......Which is actually how  Get Method is read.So modified my code as

```
PostSubmitter post = new PostSubmitter();
        post.Url = "http://192.168.0.1/Invoice/Invoice1.aspx";
        post.PostItems.Add("subscriberid", subscriberid.ToString());
        post.PostItems.Add("StartDate", StartDate);
        post.PostItems.Add("EndDate", EndDate);
        post.PostItems.Add("AdvanceBillDate", AdvanceBillDate);
        post.Type = PostSubmitter.PostTypeEnum.Get;
        try
        {
            string res = post.Post();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare your request from C# with one done in a browser.

Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to do this.

You should be able to compare everything from header values, to complete post data, etc. and be able to figure out what you have missing.  I would suspect you are leaving out required a value and the server application is throwing a (likely unexpected) exception.

Comment: i tried the post url link in browser it works fine without any throwing any exception.....

Comment: Use fiddler to compare the working request with your code.  It is an Http "debugger".